# Close the application when it goes to the background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When the application is sent to the background, i need the application to shutdown completely. Presently, when my app goes to the background, and when i call it back it shows the view i was working before it went to the background.

I am doing this to release memory.

How can i do this programatically ?

Comment: What do you mean by *am doing this to release memory*?

Comment: When the application comes back from the background, my UITableView scrolls very slowly (it has images too). So i thought to close the app completely when it goes to the background.

Comment: in that case..you should rethink of why it is scrolling slow..user won't like it that he has to wait everytime when launching app..

Comment: the tableview has lots of images. This is why it takes a long time to scroll

Comment: you won't need this if you release memory properly.

Comment: @HelmiB I am using ARC, so can't release memory

Comment: @shajem then why you need to release memory in the first place?

Comment: @HelmiB It slows down the application. I think that ARC releases/deallocs memory at the AutoreleasePool. So until that happence my application slows down due to lack of memory :S . If i could release it before, then i would be able to release some memory and speed up my application . your thoughts ?

Comment: @shajem i'm not the expert in ARC, but for what i read, it shouldn't happend like what you said, slow down memory and leak shouldn't happend, well at least reduce that. or You disable ARC of specific class you afraid leak would happend and You want to handle memory release/dealloc on your own.

Comment: I am not sure, but some times when i send the application to the background, and bring it back to foreground the scrolling of tableview and scrolling of other views gets very slow. I think this is because of an memory issue. What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to **YES** on info.plist

More info here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: I am doing this to preserve memory, because the tableview (which has loads of images) takes time to load when it comes from the background and slows the scrolling. So will this approach work ? (i need your opinion)

Comment: you need to cache the images..look up https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage  ..this way it won't load the images again and again..other than that.how large is the images..in size and pixels

Comment: 40-70 KB. height and width varies the user could upload whatever height or width he prefers

Comment: i think you are using synchronous request..and that is why your UI is blocked every time the cell is shown and the table view waits before the image is downloaded.. use the library i have given the link above..that will sort out the problem since it caches as well as do asynchronous requests

Comment: I am going through SDWebimage. Is this the code to cache and display the image :S `// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];` Bit confused :S

Comment: yes..it is the code...you can show a placeholder image till the image is downloaded...in my experience you should provide a placeholder image if you can ..since otherwise..the image won't be updated until user scrolls back and forth to current cell..if you provide a placeholder..image updates as soon image is finished..

Answer (score 3):

Go to your configuration (e.g plist file) and add the following tag : 
`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` and set it to `true`

Comment: I am doing this to preserve memory, because the tableview (which has loads of images) takes time to load when it comes from the background and slows the scrolling. So will this approach work ? (i need your opinion)

Answer (score 2):

Do not prevent your app from multitasking just because you have memory issues. What you should do is optimize your code and correct these issues.

Look at this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) and the methods that it mentions, they will allow you to know if your application is going to the background for example so that you can release some memory.

Comment: @shajem: actually both other answers are right for your question, but sch is giving you a very good advice, too